# Rails Form Helper unexpected params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Slot has many students
My form:

```
<%= form_for(@slot) do |f| %>

  <% @slot.students.each do |student| %>
    <%= f.fields_for student, index: student.id do |student_form| %>
      ID: <%= student.id %>
      Present: <%= student_form.check_box :present %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And slots controller get this params hash:

```
"slot"=>{
 "student"=>{"1"=>{"present"=>"0"},
 "2"=>{"present"=>"0"},
 "3"=>{"present"=>"0"},
 "4"=>{"present"=>"0"},
 "5"=>{"present"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Update Slot",
 "id"=>"125251"}
```

Because I need student's Id but I don't know how I can get it through each student. This way is much easier for me:

```
"slot"=>{
     "student"=>{{"id"=>"1","present"=>"0"},
     {"id"=>"2","present"=>"0"},
     {"id"=>"3","present"=>"0"},
     {"id"=>"4","present"=>"0"},
     {"id"=>"5","present"=>"0"},
     "commit"=>"Update Slot",
     "id"=>"125251"}
```

How could I edit the form? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read up about [`fields_for` collections](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

```
#app/views/slots/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @slot do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :students, @slot.students do |student_form| %>
      ID: <%= student.id %>
      Present: <%= student_form.check_box :present %><br>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above should work.

The way to see if it *is* working is to look for `students_attributes` in the params hash. If your params don't have `_attributes` appended, it's not working:

```
"slot"=>{
 "students_attributes"=>
  {
    "1"=>{"present"=>"0"},
    "2"=>{"present"=>"0"},
    "3"=>{"present"=>"0"},
    "4"=>{"present"=>"0"},
    "5"=>{"present"=>"0"},
  }
  "commit"=>"Update Slot",
  "id"=>"125251"}
```

This is how `fields_for` should work. Not building the associative objects, or not having those objects present, will prevent the `_attributes` param from being passed, thus preventing [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) from updating the fields as required.

--

You don't need to explicitly define the `ids`, `fields_for` / `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should do that for you:

```
#app/models/slot.rb
class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end

#app/controllers/slots_controller.rb
class SlotsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @slot = Slot.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @slot = Slot.find params[:id]
      @slot.update slot_params
   end

   private

   def slot_params
      params.require(:slot).permit(students_attributes: [:present])
   end
end
```